# VBA - Insert Current Date in Column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using two files let's name it `File 1` and `File 2` my script append the data from `File 1` to `File 2` now every time I append `File 2` i want insert `Current Date` from my Column.

*File 1:*

```
Header 1 |  Header 2 | Header 3|
1        |  1        |         |
1        |  1        |         |
```

*File 2*

```
 Header 1 |  Header 2 | Header 3|
    a     |  a        | 3/3/2016|
    a     |  a        | 3/3/2016|
```

*Sample Output:*

```
Header 1 |  Header 2 | Header 3|
    a    |  a        |3/3/2016 |
    a    |  a        |3/3/2016 |
    1    |  1        |4/4/2016 |
    1    |  1        |4/4/2016 |
```

As you can see the sample output above inserted the current date in `Header 3.

My problem is that if i append the data from `File 2` it densest return the current date in `Header 3` but if I append it again it updates the last one.
to make it clear let's give another example.

Sample Out: (This is the output of my script)

```
Header 1 |  Header 2 | Header 3|
    a    |  a        |3/3/2016 |
    a    |  a        |3/3/2016 |
    1    |  1        |         |
    1    |  1        |         |
```

If I append again the data from `File 1` this is now the output

```
 Header 1 |  Header 2 | Header 3|
     a    |  a        |3/3/2016 |
     a    |  a        |3/3/2016 |
     1    |  1        |4/4/2016 |
     1    |  1        |4/4/2016 |       
     1    |  1        |         |
     1    |  1        |         |
```

I want to insert the current date every time i append a new data, my code insert the date one step behind and i'm connfused gagin with my code @.@ Please Help me!

*My Code:*

```
Public Sub addweeklydata()

Dim file1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim file2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

Dim Rng As Range

    Set Sheet1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Sheets(1)
    Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)

    lastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 4).Value = Date

    Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 'assuming no blank rows/column
    Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, Rng.Columns.Count) 'exclude header
Next
    Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value

 Sheet2.Parent.Close True 'save changes
 Sheet1.Parent.Close False 'don't save

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not add date to file1 before exporting?

Comment: @SiddharthRout i realllllly want to do that, but my IS wants everything to be automated haha

Comment: Yes I was talking about automation. Also I have a different (faster) approach in mind. Are you oopen for that?

Comment: sure :) i'm still learning so everything is fine by me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the data after you copy the files, something like this:

```
Public Sub addweeklydata()

Dim file1 As Excel.Workbook
Dim file2 As Excel.Workbook
Dim Sheet1 As Worksheet
Dim Sheet2 As Worksheet

Dim Rng As Range

    Set Sheet1 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox1.Text).Sheets(1)
    Set Sheet2 = Workbooks.Open(TextBox2.Text).Sheets(1)

    lastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To lastRow
        Sheet2.Cells(i, 4).Value = Date

        Set Rng = Sheet1.Range("A1").CurrentRegion 
        Set Rng = Rng.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Rng.Rows.Count - 1, Rng.Columns.Count) 
    Next

    Sheet2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize( _
                Rng.Rows.Count, Rng.Columns.Count).Value = Rng.Value

     lastRow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
     For i = 2 To lastRow
          if not cbool(len(Sheet2.Cells(i, 4))) then Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) = Date
     next i

    Sheet2.Parent.Close True 'save changes
    Sheet1.Parent.Close False 'don't save

End Sub
```

I have not tested it, but the idea of the second loop is to add data only if the cell is empty. You can optimize it.

Comment: thank you for your quick response :)
im going to try now

Comment: _red line_ `if not len(Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) then Sheet2.Cells(i, 4) = Date`

Comment: Try again after the fix.

Comment: it's still _red line_ i dont really know how to debug it @.@

Comment: I missed a comma there :) Now fixed

Answer (score 2):

Here is a faster way of doing it

**Logic:**

1. Read the text file in memory and store it in an array
2. Insert date in the 3rd column

**Code**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim MyData As String, strData() As String
    Dim TempAr

    '~~> Read the text file in memory in one go
    Open "C:\File1.Txt" For Binary As #1
    MyData = Space$(LOF(1))
    Get #1, , MyData
    Close #1
    strData() = Split(MyData, vbCrLf)

    For i = LBound(strData) To UBound(strData)
        TempAr = Split(strData(i), "|")
        If Len(Trim(TempAr(2))) = 0 Then TempAr(2) = Date
        strData(i) = Join(TempAr, "|")

        Debug.Print strData(i)
    Next i

    '~~> strData now has all the data from file1 with date in it
    '~~> Simply append the array to the 2nd text file
End Sub
```